# Is there a way to set the active menu's text as page title?

Tags: 7

I would like to set the active menu's text as the page title in drupal7. I tried using the page title module and found no replacement patterns to set the active menu as the page title. Any help is widely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you change the node title to be the same as the menu? Since your menu is static the page title can be too.

Comment: As per my need I should have the Head and page title different, hence I cannot go with the above implementation !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with this link http://sivaji.drupalgardens.com/how-set-custom-page-title-drupal-7.

There exists no way to dynamically set the active menu as the page title, but with the Classes_array from the vars, we can check the page's id and then set the page title as per our need.

In my case I used a if check to check the page id (Page-contact's page title to Contact) and so. It worked for me though, but still found no way to dynamically set the title from the active menu !

Comment: You are asking for a rare feature, but there are no replacement tokens for the menu items. (And why should there be, menu titles are usually shorter then the real titles). You could try to write a custom drupal modules that hooks onto the menu API ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/group/menu/7 ). But not sure whitch title they mean there.